# Plotting Taylor polynomial for sin(x) in GNU Octave

Tags: octave

I'm attempting to plot the Taylor polynomial for `sin(x)` at `a=0` with input of `m` degrees, in GNU Octave. `sin(x)` is plotted along with the estimation.

```
m = int8(input('Input integer m in [0,10]: '));
if m<0 || m>10
    disp('Thanks for playing');
    return;
  end
x = [-5:0.01:5];

y1 = sin(x);
for n=0:m
  y2 = ((-1).^n/factorial(2*n+1))*x.^(2*n+1);
  plot(y2);
  hold on;
  end
plot(y1,'linewidth',4)
ylim([-1.5,1.5]);
```

Above code prints the following image:

[image]

What is causing every estimation to have so few inflection points? I have tried setting `xlim([-5,5])` but that did not fix my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you only evaluate each term without taking the summation.

You need to initialize `y2` and update the sum per iteration:

```
y2 = 0  % initialize y2

for n = 0:m
  y2 = (-1).^n/factorial(2*n+1) * x.^(2*n+1) + y2;  % add to previous y2
  plot(y2);
  hold on;
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the correction. To ask a possibly obvious question, does the need to initialize come from the definition of a Taylor series itself?

Comment: Here it's just a programming issue. If `y2` doesn't get initialized before the loop, `y2` will be undefined in the first iteration and will throw an error when we try to do `... + y2`.

Comment: Ah, got it.  I was conflating your method with the summing a Taylor series, but also realized that wouldn't make sense/be needed for only one value of ```m```.